# How do I move files to new folder based on timestamp dynamically without manually changing the script?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, command-line, fedora

```
# Create a folder
mkdir archived_PA_2022-01_2022-06

# Move files to new folder
find ./ -newermt "2021-12-31" ! -newermt '2022-06-28' -exec mv /var/log/pentaho/PA –t archived_PA_2022-01_2022-06 {} +

# Archive folder 
zip -r archived_PA_2022-01_2022-06.zip /var/log/pentaho/archived_PA_2022-01_2022-06
```

I have this Unix script here to move files for the previous 6 months to a new folder.
What I want is to move files dynamically.

For example, today, July 6, 2023, I want to move files to a new folder named 'archived_PA_2023-01-05_2023-07-05' based on the timestamp from January 5, 2023, to July 5, 2023. And for July 7, 2023, I want to move files to a new folder named 'archived_PA_2023-01-06_2023-07-06' based on the timestamp from January 6, 2023, to July 6, 2023, and so on.

I want this process to be dynamic, where the timestamp is automatically determined, and a new folder is created accordingly, without manually changing the script each time I run it.

Is there a way for me to achieve this?

Comment: `date -d "6 months ago" +%Y-%m-%d`

Comment: What if you run it on 2023-08-31?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.

Just use:

```
# Create a folder dynamically 
mkdir archived_PA_"$(date -d "6 months ago" +%Y-%m-%d)"_"$(date -d "1 day ago" +%Y-%m-%d)"

# Move files to new folder dynamically
find ./ -newermt "6 months ago" ! -newermt "1 day ago" -exec mv -t archived_PA_"$(date -d "6 months ago" +%Y-%m-%d)"_"$(date -d "1 day ago" +%Y-%m-%d)" {} +
```

Comment: Note that `-newermt "1 day ago"` same as `-newermt yesterday` means yesterday **at the same time** (unless there's been a DST clock change), so if run at 12:00 for instance, you'll move yesterday's morning ones. Same goes for the `6 months ago` one.